# Only show published pages in Bolt

Tags: backend, bolt-cms

I know it's a quite basic question, but I couldn't find an answer in die documentation: Is it possible to show only published pages in the Bolt backend? I saw that there is a `filter` entry on the right, but I couldn't find out if there's a syntax for filtering pages by their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that is possible without hacking the back-end.

But you can easily do this on a front-end page that is only accessible for logged-in users:

`{% if user.username %}
    {# looping through your published pages with a link to the edit in the backend based on the pages' ID #}
{% endif %}`